# cmake build problem when building code for avr

Tags: cmake, avr

I am trying to build a sample project for avr atmega328p. And I am facing a strange issue. I have following directory structure.

```
inc/core/device_support.h
src/main.c
src/core/device_support.c
```

I have two project setups, one using make and another one using cmake. When I build using make everything works fine. but when I use cmake it doesn't compile ok. ( .text section is not same if I run `avr-size -A myProject.elf` and it doesn't run correctly on target mcu). But if I run the compile command manually in cmake project directory with build directory as working directory everything works fine.

I have narrowed down the problem to the fact that if we run compile command form core `/home/user/avr/build/core` it doesn't work, and If I run command while in `/home/user/avr/build` build directory It works fine. I have no clue to why this may be happening.

My question is why being on different directory messes up compilation and how can I fix it in cmake.

with make I have something like:

```
avr-gcc -DARDUINO=10808 -DF_CPU=160000000L -I/home/user/avr/inc/core -mmcu=atmega328p -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -Os -w -g -MD -MT /home/user/avr/src/core/device_support.c -o /home/user/avr/build/core/device_support.o
```

and with cmake auto generated script I have:

```
cd /home/user/avr/build/core && avr-gcc -DARDUINO=10808 -DF_CPU=160000000L -I/home/user/avr/inc/core -mmcu=atmega328p -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -Os -w -g -MD -MT -o src/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core/device_support.o /home/user/avr/src/core/device_support.c
```

**UPDATE 01:**

avr-size -A myProject.elf output (cmake):

```
 section                    size      addr
.data                         0   8388864
.text                       740         0
.bss                          9   8388864
.comment                     17         0
.note.gnu.avr.deviceinfo     64         0
.debug_aranges              120         0
.debug_info                3537         0
.debug_abbrev              1965         0
.debug_line                1044         0
.debug_frame                124         0
.debug_str                 1175         0
.debug_loc                  843         0
.debug_ranges                40         0
Total                      9678
```

avr-size -A myProject.elf output (make):

```
    section                     size      addr
.data                          0   8388864
.text                        930         0
.bss                           9   8388864
.comment                      17         0
.note.gnu.avr.deviceinfo      64         0
.debug_aranges               104         0
.debug_info                 3559         0
.debug_abbrev               2002         0
.debug_line                 1134         0
.debug_frame                 180         0
.debug_str                  1139         0
.debug_loc                  1154         0
.debug_ranges                 24         0
Total                      10316
```

You can see the difference in .text section. Its a simple led blink code When I run this on device in cmake case LED stays on at sometimes and completely off at others. And If I compile the same code manually by running the same commands from cmake's output, but with build directory as my working directory then LED blinks as expected.

There are no errors during build in either case. The only difference is being in build directory. If I build manually and my working directory is not build then It fails in this case as well. For some reason being in build directory during compilation is important and I have no clue why.

**Update 02:** 
Example code has been upload to : https://github.com/systemangle/mcve_avr

Please see project readme.

Comment: "it doesn't run correctly on target mcu" - Elaborate this. Do you have any warning or error during the project's build? What is printed when you tried to run the elf created?

Comment: You only posted commands to compile `device_support.o`. Maybe the problem is in the linker command line? Can you post all messages from cmake and make?

Comment: @KamilCuk Linker commands runs fine when I run it manually simply by copying it from the output. I will update the question with all the commands. But as I said each compiled object file is different in size if I using cmake and the same code file produces correct object file size if I compile manually by simply copying the command from the output, Only important thing is I must be in build directory while compiling.

Comment: Then let's inspect object `.o` files. Try to create a smallest `.c` file for which the difference is observable, post it, post generated assembly output. Is the difference observable in `main.o` or `device_support.o` or both? Is `cmake` or `make` even relevant to the question? Can you create an MCVE, a small script to replicate the problem? Would be great to include also `cat <<EOF >file.c ....` file content and `avr-gcc ....` `cd .... && avr-gcc ..` compile commands and outputs of `avr-size` of both files in one script. The issue is strange. Can you post `avr-gcc` version?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes all .o files are different using cmake. I will try making MCVE.  Relevance of make and cmake is as such that I am trying to port a make based project to cmake. what I did is replaced Makefile with CMakeLists.txt and created toolchain for cmake to select appropriate compiler etc. I tried with both gcc 8.3.0 and from arduino gcc  5.4.0. As a matter of fact for MCVE I am trying to port arduino files to my cmake project setup. So far I am seeing similar results. I will share it after it is done.

Answer (score 0):

*For some reason being in build directory during compilation is important and I have no clue why*

Then you probably already have the answer. The problem doesn't seem to be CMake related.
May be you can try an in-source build with cmake and see what happen.
Otherwise if you want to mimic the hand-written Makefile behaviour you can avoid using any add_subdirectory and only write a big fat CMakeLists.txt at the root of your project.

All that said, if compilation output vary depending on *where* you are when the compiler is invoked then I think you'd better off asking question to the people providing the cross-compiler about this weird behavior.

Did you try hand compilation a file while being in a different directory?
Does this change the outputed object file?